# Login and Logout issue using facebook-php-sdk

Tags: facebook

I am working on website, in which i want integrate the facebook login with my website login system. I have integrated facebook-php-sdk in code. Login functionality work fine. Below are the points that I have issue...

1. **Once logged out and click on login the facebook login screen not open.**
2. **Once logged out and refresh the page, the login deatils is displaying again. And login button disappears.**
3. **If the above two points will solved then how to maintain login session through out the website?**

For above 2 points I have used the below code.

```
    require 'src/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
      'secret' => SECRET_KEY,
    ));

    session_start();



    if($_REQUEST['msg'] == 'logout'){
        setcookie('fbsr_'.$facebook->getAppId(), '', (time() - 3600), '/', 'domain.com');
        $sts = $facebook->destroySession();         
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: index.php");
        //echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=index.php">';
    } 

    $userId = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($userId && !isset($_SESSION['fbdata'])) {
        $_SESSION['fbdata'] = array("userid" => $userId);       
    }

<?php if ($userId) {
        $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId); ?>
        Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
    <?php } ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId      : '<?= YOUR_APP_ID ?>',
                    status     : true, 
                    cookie     : true,
                    xfbml      : true,
                    oauth      : true,
                });

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
                    //window.location.reload();
                });
            };

            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>
        <br />
        <br />
        <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?msg=logout"; ?>">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Hello all, I have never seen any answers from anybody on this issue here. If anybody know please answer this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on my questions below.
1.Once logged out and click on login the facebook login screen not open.

> > Facebook cookies was not deleted or we can say was not removed from starage. For this I have used this below javascript

```
    
    function removeCookie(  name, path, domain) {

        if ( getCookie( name ) )

        {

            document.cookie = name + '=' + ( ( path ) ? ';path=' + path : '') + ( ( domain ) ? ';domain=' + domain : '' ) + ';expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT';

        }

    }
```

It works for me.

2.Once logged out and refresh the page, the login deatils is displaying again. And login button disappears.

> > The same reason as above question.

3.If the above two points will solved then how to maintain login session through out the website?

> > Maintain the fb id in session and when request coming for logout remove cookie and destroy the session.